# Nested Models in Loopback Android SDK

Tags: android, mongodb, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have a loopback instance with MongoDB backend, and have defined a model that has a nested (anonymous) model called 'location' as a property:

```
  "name": "thing",
  "plural": "things",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "title": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "description": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "location": {
      "lat": {
         "type": "string"
      },
      "lng": {
         "type": "string"
      }
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

In my android project, i'm using the loopback sdk to fetch all "thing" models into instance of a thing.java class that extends from loopback's model class.

```
ThingRepository repository = restAdapter.createRepository(Thing.class);
    repository.findAll(/* callback code ommitted */)

public class Thing extends Model {
    private String id;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private Location location;
    /* getters/setters removed */
  }
```

When I fetch all "things" from the server, and they all look fine except the nested "location" is always null.  I've verified that I can fetch the Things from loopback's REST apis, with the location correctly populated. But it seems like the loopback client just wont deserialize and populate 'location'. "Location" is a simple java class with just 2 ints (lat and long).  I've tried making it extend from 'Model' as well, but it still comes back as null.

```
public class Location extends Model {
    private String lat;
    private String lng;
    /* getters/setters removed */
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This functionnality does not seem to be supported at the moment.](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-sdk-android/issues/62)

> We should hopefully get this for free once we replace our hand-written JSON parser with a proper library supporting custom annotations

In the meantime, a no-brainer solution for you would be to create a `location` model, add a `thing` `HasOne` `location` relation, and use "api/thing/{id}/location" endpoint.

Or you can fork [the project](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-sdk-android), change the JSON parsing library and make a pull request. It's up to you ;)

EDIT : Or, you've probably already thought of that but an even more simple solution, drop the nested object and use two classic properties `location_lat` `location_lng`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info, I think you're right.  I'll leave this open for a little while longer, and then set your answer as the solution.

Comment: I added an other solution, more simple

Answer (score 0):

I have changed just few lines of sdk, and now it can parse all nested models recursively

```
compile 'com.github.farruxx:loopback-sdk-android:v1.6.3'
```